# How do I make my discord bot reply to a mention?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my discord bot to reply when someone mentions it. For example, if @someone types "Hello @bot" I want my bot to reply "Hello @someone!".

I tried several methods:
1.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content == ("@bot"):
    await message.channel.send("Hello {}".format(message.author.mention) + "!")
```

and even this,

```
@client.event
    async def on_message(message):
      if message.author == client.user:
        return
      if message.content.startswith("@bot"):
        await message.channel.send("Hello {}".format(message.author.mention) + "!")
```

But none of these worked.

So how do I make my discord bot reply to a mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord mentions aren't processed like that, their internal format looks like this:

```c
<@{id_here}>  - Normal mention
<@!{id_here}> - Nick mention
<@&{id_here}> - Role mention
<#{id_here}>  - Channel mention
```

You can make a simple regex:

```py
import re

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
  
    pattern = re.compile(f"hello <@!?{client.user.id}>") # The exclamation mark is optional

    if pattern.match(message.content.lower()) is not None: # Checking whether the message matches our pattern
        await message.channel.send(f"Hello {message.author.mention}!")
```